# Сложности при создании нового пользователя через форму django

Tags: django, django-model

Я работаю над регистрацией на сайте. Моя проблема заключается в том, что встроенная модель User сохраняется удачно, а элемент другой связанной модели не может сохраниться и где-то теряется (kind). Предполагаю, что проблема с самой неправильной организацией .save(), но точно не понимаю в чем проблема. Тест на создание нового пользователя проходит хорошо. В результате создается пользователь с введенными данными, за исключением Kind. Делал частично по этому туториалу: https://tproger.ru/translations/extending-django-user-model/ , но видимо где-то допустил ошибку. Очень надеюсь на помощь!

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Kind(models.Model):
    class Kinds(models.TextChoices):
        M = '1', "М"
        F = '2', "Ж"

    class Confirmations(models.TextChoices):
        S = '1', "Не подтвержден"
        N = '2', "Подтвержден"

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="avatars/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Kinds.choices, verbose_name='Пол')
    confirmation = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='1', choices=Confirmations.choices, verbose_name='Подтверждение')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Kind.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from Вход.forms import *
from .models import *


def registrationn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        kind_form = UserKindForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and kind_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save()
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()

            new_kind = kind_form.save()
            new_kind.save()

            return render(request, 'registration/registration_done.html', {'new_user': new_user, 'new_kind': new_kind})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        kind_form = UserKindForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'kind_form': kind_form})

...
```

Forms.py

```
from .models import Kind
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

class UserKindForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Kind
        fields = ('kind', )
```

Шаблон 1

```
{% extends "Главная/Общее.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Create an account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Register</h2>

<form id="formm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ kind_form.as_p }}
</form>

<input form="formm" type="submit" value="Register">

{% endblock %}
```

Шаблон 2

```
{% extends "Главная/Общее.html" %}

{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Уважаемый пользователь {{ new_user.first_name }}, мы рассмотрим вашу заявку в течении суток!</h1>
    <p><a href="/">На главную</a>.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось получить ответ на свой вопрос. Оказывается моя форма работала вообще не с новым пользователем, а другим пользователем из базы данных. Кто делает регистрацию, никогда не указывайте instance=... это большая ошибка. Еще не создан пользователь чтобы работать с ним.

Мне помог этот код:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        kind_form = UserKindForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and kind_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save()
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()

            new_user.profile.kind = kind_form.cleaned_data.get('kind')
            new_user.profile.save()

            return render(request, 'registration/registration_done.html', {'new_user': new_user, 'kind_form': kind_form})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        kind_form = UserKindForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'kind_form': kind_form})
```